# GraphQl where does not filter in Staging

Tags: c#, graphql, graphql-csharp

I have a GraphQl query that works in development but doesn't work in Staging.

```
query all_Products($region: Alpha2Code!) {
    variantsByregion(region: $region
      where:{isB2B:{eq:true}}
      ) {
        items {
          productCode,
          isB2B
        }
    }
}
```

if I run the above query in my development it will filter with isB2B but as soon as I use this query in Staging I get whole data.

Comment: Why GraphQL works in different environments please explain and give some details more

Comment: I didn't get your meaning across, by the way when I debug it in my local and use   Insomnia it works in my local but  as soon as I use my Staging (change Url to my Staging server) I don't get the expected result.